# Index of an a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't seem to figure this out and have looked at some previous questions.

It's pretty simple problem but can't seem to get the results. I have a Div element and I append a elements to the dynamically. When the user clicks one of the elements inside I want it's index in accordance with that div element. So far I have not been able to succeed and I don't understand why.

**Code So Far**

**HTML**

```
 <li class = "has-dropdown">
    <li class = "dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Chains</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <div class = "dropdown-content" id = "chainNav">
             </div>
        </ul>
     </li>
</li>
```

**THE JS**

```
for (var i = 0; i < chainList.length; ++i) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var chainNav = document.getElementById("chainNav");
    a.textContent = chainList[i];
    chainNav.appendChild(a);
  }

$('a', $('#chainNav')).click( function() {
    var index = $(this).closest('div').index();
    alert(index);
} );
```

Chain List is created dynamically and usually contains some arbitrary letters like so

```
chainList = [A, E, F, I, D, G];
```

The code runs and the a elements are generated. I just need the index of each one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `on` delegated event for click to work, since you are dynamically adding an element to a DOM

```js
chainList = ['A', 'E', 'F', 'I', 'D', 'G'];
for (var i = 0; i < chainList.length; ++i) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var chainNav = document.getElementById("chainNav");
    a.textContent = chainList[i];
    chainNav.appendChild(a);
  }
$('#chainNav').on('click','a',function() {
       var index = $(this).index();
       alert(index);
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <li class = "has-dropdown">
    <li class = "dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Chains</a>
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <div class = "dropdown-content" id = "chainNav">
             </div>
        </ul>
     </li>
</li>
```

Comment: it now returns every element index as zero

Comment: ya because you have just 1 div there and and its index is 0;

Comment: ah I just figured it out with some help of your code! Thank you :)

Answer (score -1):

```
 $('#chainNav').on('click','a',function() {
   var index = ($('#chainNav a').index($(this))) + 1;  
   alert (index);
}
```

that fixed it and returned the numbers I needed inside the div element.